# Calling A List of a Hashmap of a list. (Java)

Tags: java, android

This is my variable

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I keep adding info to the usersInfo with

```
hashMap.put(TAG_USERNAME,
data_obj.getString(TAG_USERNAME));
usersInfo.add(hashMap);
```

How can I print this array or print from an index to get the info put in it?

Comment: Are you asking how to print a value? How to get a value from a map? From a list? Please be more specific.

Comment: from usersInfo, how can I get the value of TAG_USERNAME by an index.

Comment: If you have multiple hashmaps in `usersInfo` they might have different values for the same tag.

Comment: You can't get the value of a map key by index because maps aren't ordered. Why would you want to anyway?

Comment: So how can I get the value of TAG_USERNAME put into the usersInfo by index?

Comment: You can't put or retrieve a map value by index. You're not doing a great job at explaining yourself.

Comment: `usersInfo[0].get("TAG_USERNAME")` - will get the tag from the first hashmap in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the values of the Arraylist as follows:

```
userInfo.stream.forEach((map)-> {
    for(String key : map.getKeys()){
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + map.get(key));
    }
})
```

Or if you want to get specific map at some index, you use the following:

```
Map map = userInfo.get(0);
for(String key : map.getKeys()){
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + map.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for(Map map :usersInfo){
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
String key = entry.getKey();
String value = entry.getValue();
```

}
   }

Comment: You should explain what this code does. Don't just paste it here and walk away.